# Android App Crashes on Start Up

Tags: java, android, eclipse, crash, crash-reports

I created an app game that runs perfectly on the eclipse emulator. However, when my friends download it in the Google Play Store it crashes on start up. I have attached the crash report from my Google Developer Dashboard, it says the crash is caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException but I can't figure out how to fix this. Can you guys please help me? I've been struggling with this for a few days.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL4E6.png

Comment: if I was to tell you that you got an exception for class not found.... what would you think that meant? thats the exception you got. make sure the class exists....and if it down. paste the code of that class

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Please read [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), which applies to exceptions as well, then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion I have - please check if user sometimes earlier already installed and tested older version of the game, and possibly old corrupted data stay at the device memory. In this case un-installing the app thru app manager, and cleaning-up the related data may help. Good luck!